# Variable scope in Sass for loops

Tags: css, sass

In one of my SCSS scripts, I discovered that I had accidentally given a `@for` loop counter the same name as different, global variable, *but everything still worked as expected*.

For example, paste this example script into http://sassmeister.com/:

```
$w: white;
$r: red;
$b: blue;
$y: yellow;

//...

$test: '';
//Accidentally using an existing variable name ($r) as the counter:
@for $r from 1 through 10 {
  @if($test != '') { $test: $test + ', '; }
  $test: $test + $r;
}

.someclass {
  /*Note: $r is 'red', not the @for counter. @for loops create their own scope?*/
  color: $r;
  /*All the @for counters. @for created a *local* $r, but accessed the *global* $test...*/
  something: unquote($test);
}
```

...and the CSS will look like:

```
.someclass {
  /*Note: $r is 'red', not the @for counter. @for loops create their own scope?*/
  color: red;
  /*All the @for counters. @for created a *local* $r, but accessed the *global* $test...*/
  something: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10;
}
```

So, I would have thought that the `@for` loop changed `$r` from `red` to `10` by the time it was used in `.someclass`, but (luckily) it didn't. This indicates that the loop works in its own local scope, but it still accesses the global `$test` variable, even without using a `!global` flag.

And now I'm confused. The [docs](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_scope_and_content_blocks) state that mixins have a local scope, but I haven't found any documentation about for loop scoping. *Is this "hybrid" scoping a documented feature - the loop counter is in some local scope, while the loop "body" works in the parent scope - or is it a bug in the SCSS compiler?*

Comment: You don't seem to have an actual problem here.  The only people who can answer "is this a bug" are the maintainers of Sass.

Comment: @cimmanon - Well, you never know. There are people out there who know the inner workings of Sass way (way way) better than I do. Anyway, I have now submitted an Issue on their github page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is a bug in the compiler as I believe this to be the intended behavior of the @for loop, but you're correct in that that it's not [documented](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#_10). I would [submit a request](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues) to have this clarified / added into the official docs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have submitted an Issue for this on github. If anyone is interested: https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1863

Comment: Answer: Control structures use a ["semi-global" scope](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1863#issuecomment-149702641) which creates its own local variables, but can still access other global variables.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for following up